# how to get data in single row in <td>, multiple entry in database with same id

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

**table structure is like as:**

```
medicine table                    component table
id | name                        id | medicine_id | component_name
----------------                -----------------------------------
1  |  a                           1 |      1      |       aaaa
2  |  b                           2 |      1      |       bbbb   
3  |  b                           3 |      1      |       cccc
                                  4 |      2      |       abab
                                  5 |      2      |       baba
                                  6 |      3      |       zzzz
```

**My query is**

```
$query = "SELECT med_name, component_name FROM medicine left JOIN component ON medicine.id=component.medicine_id order by medicine.med_name";
```

**PHP Code**

```
$result = $mysqli -> query($query);

while ($row = $result -> fetch_array()) {

echo '<tr><td>' . $row['med_name'] . '</td><td>' . $row['component_name'] . '</td><td>' . $row['component_name'] . '</td><td>' . $row['component_name'] . '</td><td>' . $row['component_name'] . '</td><td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><i class="fa fa-edit text-success text-active"></i> Edit</a></td></tr>';

}
```

**with this code my html output is like:**

```
medicine | component1 | component2 | component3 | component4
-------------------------------------------------------------
  a      |    aaaa    |    aaaa    |    aaaa    |    aaaa
  a      |    bbbb    |    bbbb    |    bbbb    |    bbbb
  a      |    cccc    |    cccc    |    cccc    |    cccc
  b      |    abab    |    abab    |    abab    |    abab
  b      |    baba    |    baba    |    baba    |    baba
  c      |    zzzz    |    zzzz    |    zzzz    |    zzzz
```

**but I want html output as:**

```
 medicine | component1 | component2 | component3 | component4
--------------------------------------------------------------
    a     |    aaaa    |    bbbb    |    cccc    |
    b     |    abab    |    baba    |            |
    c     |    zzzz    |            |            |
```

Comment: In your table structure under medicine, you have the id 2 & 3 with the same name of 'b'. Was this a mistake and you meant for #3 to be 'c'?

Comment: Sorry! it was writing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is just a bit more complicated that what you're doing. Your query seems fine. But after you fetch the results there's a little more work to do to determine how the table should be produced. I would start by fetching the rows into a multidimensional array, where multiple component rows are stored under each medicine name, like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $medicines[$row['med_name']][] = $row;
}
```

Then you'll need to find the maximum number of components for any of the medicines you fetched, so you can know how many columns your table should have.

```
$component_columns = max(array_map('count', $medicines));
```

Then you can iterate your array of medicines and output each one as a row with its components as additional columns.

```
foreach ($medicines as $medicine => $components) {

    // start the row and echo the medicine name
    echo "<tr><td>$medicine</td>";

    // echo the components, keeping track of how many you've done so far
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($components as $component) {
        echo "<td>$component[component_name]</td>";
        $i++;
    }

    // then echo empty cells to fill the rest of the row
    for (; $i < $component_columns; $i++) {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    echo '<tr>';

}
```

By the way, it looks like you're using the medicine id in a link in your HTML, but if you want to add that, you'll need to be sure to include that in the selected columns in your query as well.

Answer (score 0):

when i apply this pagination it break any random single row to double row.
And its pagination is like"1|2|3|4|5|6|so on" **not like** "1|2|3|4|5|last" or "First|4|5|6|last".

```
   function generate_page_links($cur_page, $num_pages) {
                    $page_links = '';

                    // If this page is not the first page, generate the "previous" link
                    if ($cur_page > 1) {
                        $page_links .= '<li><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . ($cur_page - 1) . '">&laquo;</a></li> ';
                    } else {
                        $page_links .= '<li  class="disabled"><a href="#" >&laquo; </a></li>';
                    }

                    // Loop through the pages generating the page number links
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
                        if ($cur_page == $i) {
                            $page_links .= '  <li class="active"><a href="#" >' . $i . '</a></li>';
                        } else {
                            $page_links .= ' <li><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $i . '"> ' . $i . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    }

                    // If this page is not the last page, generate the "next" link
                    if ($cur_page < $num_pages) {
                        $page_links .= ' <li><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . ($cur_page + 1) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';
                    } else {
                        $page_links .= '<li  class="disabled"><a href="#" >&raquo;</a></li>';
                    }

                    return $page_links;
                }
```